# NSMenu items greyed/disabled for not apparent reason

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

I have the following code that starts up a "tray icon" and adds a NSMenu to it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TrayIcon : NSObject

@property(strong) NSStatusItem *statusItem;

- (void)makeTrayIcon;


- (void)stopServer:(nullable id)sender;

- (void)startServer:(nullable id)sender;

@end
```

and...

```
#import "TrayIcon.h"


@implementation TrayIcon {

}
- (void)makeTrayIcon {

    // Flycut/AppController.h
    IBOutlet NSMenu *jcMenu;

    // Flycut/AppController.m
    _statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [_statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

    [_statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"16.png"]];

    [_statusItem setMenu:jcMenu];
    [_statusItem setEnabled:YES];

    //Add Menu
    {
        NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
        [menu addItemWithTitle:@"Start Server" action:@selector(startServer:) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [menu addItemWithTitle:@"Stop Server" action:@selector(stopServer:) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [menu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];
        [menu addItemWithTitle:@"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@""];
        _statusItem.menu = menu;
    }

}

- (void)stopServer:(nullable id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Stop STUFF");
}

- (void)startServer:(nullable id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Start STUFF");
}

@end
```

For some reason my menu looks like this.

[image]

Why would Quit be enabled but "Start Server" and "End Server" not be?  By using @selector(terminate:) on Start/Stop server they become enabled.  Perhaps I have bad syntax in my methods startServer and stopServer?

Comment: Just a guess, but you may need to set the `target` property on your NSMenuItems

Comment: Your menu items can't find an object in the responder chain that will respond to startServer: or stopServer:. Set the target or make sure your TrayIcon object is in the responder chain or implement the actions elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have similar code, and I removed the `-setTarget` call and saw the disabled state.

As Willeke stated, it is because your object isn't in the responder chain.

So just make sure you explicitly set the `target` property:

```
  NSMenuItem *item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start" action:@selector(startServer:) keyEquivalent:@""];
  [item setTarget:self];
  [menu addItem:item];
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work for my on second level menu item. I already added action and target for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Target should be set it is obvious, but the most important thing is that **target reference should be strong**.